# nuxt & vue - javascript redirect when working on a generated static website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a static website generated by nuxt&vue.
I would like to create a redirect for a page I'm no longer using.

So, the code I would like to run is:
`window.location.replace("[new_url]")`

**How do I make sure this javascript code is ran as soon as the user visits the page?**

Comment: Maybe fit   `router.push`

Comment: You can describe middleware and immediately redirect from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `redirect` helper from Nuxt to redirect the user to another route: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#redirect

Example to redirect from `/old` to `/new` page:

```
// page/old.vue

<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ redirect }) {
    return redirect('/new')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would you be able to expand a bit the answer? It works and all, but I would like to understand what this code does step by step :)